# RSpec tests do not display "Pending"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2

I have created the following RSpec stub in a Rails sandbox:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Viewing the list of movies" do
  it "shows the movies"
end
```

When running `rspec spec/` I expect to get this:

```
*

Pending:
  Viewing the list of movies shows the movies
    # Not Yet Implemented

Finished in 0.00025 seconds
1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

Instead, I get this:

```
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00008 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Why am I not seeing the pending tests? I've tried `rspec -fd spec/` with the same results.

This is on openSUSE 13.1 with Rails 4.1.4 and RSpec 2.13.1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I didn't save the file. /facepalm

After doing some editing and then reverting changes and saving them I'm now seeing:

```
*

Pending:
  Viewing the list of movies shows the movies
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb:4

Finished in 0.0006 seconds
1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending

Randomized with seed 8110
```